# Observablecollection Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, wpf

I am sporadically getting this error in my application.
As it seems by stack it occurs in CollectionView outside of my code and crashes the process.
I wondered if anyone experienced this and can guide me to the cause of exception.

```
    at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.System.Collections.ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, Int32 index)
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.InsertRange(Int32 index, ICollection c)
   at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.<RefreshOverride>b__1_0()
   at MS.Internal.Data.SynchronizationInfo.AccessCollection(IEnumerable collection, Action accessMethod, Boolean writeAccess)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.AccessCollection(IEnumerable collection, Action accessMethod, Boolean writeAccess)
   at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.RefreshOverride()
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.RefreshInternal()
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.ProcessChangeLog(ArrayList changeLog, Boolean processAll)
   at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.ProcessInvoke(Object arg)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.ProcessCrossThreadRequests()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   at Manager.Views.ShellView.SharedLib.Views.IClosableView.ShowDialog()
   at Manager.Modules.MainModule.Start() in D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gizmo\Manager\Manager\Modules\NonPluggable\MainModule.cs:line 253
   at Manager.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gizmo\Manager\Manager\App.xaml.cs:line 134
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at Manager.App.Main()
```

Comment: It seems to me like if a thread is modifying the collection while other is trying to read data from it.

Comment: I agree with @Gusman, try using a blocking or concurrent collection and see if that does not solve your issue.

Comment: I am using the  BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization and  BindingOperations.AccessCollection and i thought it should protect me from that cases but perhaps i might missed some of the collections.
I take a look , thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @NullReference were you able to figure out what the issue.  I think I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: No, still by this day this happens sporadically even though I have gone through all the code and there is should be no reason this happening. I suspect this is a bug in ListCollectionView but cant know for sure.

Comment: Bummer.  Were you able to work around it at all?  What was the backing collection for your CollectionView=?

Comment: No workarounds found :( CollectionView backs an ObservableCollection, if you figure it out sure let me know :)